# Windows Forms C# Linear Graph make lines Infinite

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a chart in windows forms with 1 line that goes from point (0,-6) to point (2,0).

I want this line to be infinite, or at least fill up the screen, and I can't seem to find an option to "continue" to draw the line. Can anybody help? Thanks.
[image]

EDIT: here is the code

```html
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("X_Value", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Y_Value", typeof(double));

            dt.Rows.Add(0, -6), 0);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, 0);

            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-3, 3);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(-3, 3);
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "X_Value";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Y_Value";
            chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
```

Comment: Can you post your code that you use to do this please. It's very hard to help otherwise.

Comment: That is not how lines work. You need to either feed in points far enough outside or at the very axis crossings; not hard to calculate, actually. Or you can add a LineAnnotation. Finding the right values for it is a bit tricky. You may try to make it moveable and test the resulting values..

Comment: How do you use LineAnnotation? if you put it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: I don't post answers atm; you may want to study the [numerous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+annotation) of mine for examples..

Comment: `ChartArea car = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

PointF p1 = new PointF(50, 50);
PointF p2 = new PointF(80, 60);
LineAnnotation la = new LineAnnotation();
la.LineColor = Color.OrangeRed;
la.AxisX = car.AxisX;
la.AxisY = car.AxisY;
la.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
la.X = p1.X;
la.Y = p1.Y;
la.Width = p2.X - p1.X;
la.Height = p2.Y - p1.Y;
la.IsInfinitive = true;
la.ClipToChartArea = car.Name;
chart1.Annotations.Add(la);`